# How to interprate random effects in an lme model in R

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, nested-data

I am having  trouble understanding the results of my lme model. Could someone tell me how to understand the random effects?

Here is my model:

```
pm3<-lme(X13c~treat*pp, random=~1|ind, method="ML", data=data)
```

and here is the output:

````
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: data 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | ind
         (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev: 2.309376e-05 0.5874904

Fixed effects:  X13c ~ treat * pp 
 Correlation: 
               (Intr) trtstr pp    
treatstress    -0.711              
pp             -0.980  0.697       
treatstress:pp  0.699 -0.980 -0.713

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.87673908 -0.59487102  0.06679976  0.58081038  2.79025508 

Number of Observations: 125
Number of Groups: 63 
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The random intercepts for the grouping variable `ind` are estimated to have a standard deviation of 2.309376e-05, that is 0.000023, while the residual error has a standard deviation of 0.5874904. This indicates that the component of variance attributable to `ind` is extremely small.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it.